# Obtaining all possible transitions based on the estimation of a subset of transitions through the linearity property in an optimal control problem

Tags: optimal-control

I found an article in which the authors formulated an optimal control problem based on a linear time-invariant system

$$ \dot{x}(t)=Ax(t)+Bu(t) $$

with 
initial state $ x(0)=x_0 $ and final state $ x(T)=x_T $.

The performance measure to be minimized was:

$$ \int_{0}^{T} ((x_T-x(t))^T(x_T-x(t))+\rho u(t)^Tu(t) dt $$ with $ \rho=100 $ and $ T=1$

The authors studied a set of 56 transitions, where the initial states and final states were represented by a binary vector of length 129 respectively.

Now the authors note the following:

> Importantly, because our dynamical model is linear, any possible
>   transition can be written as a linear combination of these transitions
>   (though the resulting transition may not be optimal, in terms of
>   minimum energy). Thus, our results are generally relevant to all
>   transitions.

Can somebody help me to understand this or link some information on this? In other words, after the estimation of a set of transitions based on the minimization of some performance measure, how to calculate all other transitions as a linear combination of the estimated set of transitions?

Link to article: https://www.nature.com/articles/srep30770

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If one would solve this problem for example with [PMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pontryagin%27s_maximum_principle) then you would get the following state and co-state dynamics

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\dot{x} \\ \dot{\lambda}
\end{bmatrix} = \underbrace{
\begin{bmatrix}
A & -\frac{1}{2\,\rho}B\,B^\top \\
-2\,I & -A^\top
\end{bmatrix}}_\hat{A}
\begin{bmatrix}
x \\ \lambda
\end{bmatrix} + \underbrace{
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\ 2\,I
\end{bmatrix}}_\hat{B} x_T
$$

In general those dynamics have to the following solution in time

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x(t) \\ \lambda(t)
\end{bmatrix} = e^{\hat{A}\,t} 
\begin{bmatrix}
x(0) \\ \lambda(0)
\end{bmatrix} + \int_0^t e^{\hat{A}(t - \tau)}d\tau\,\hat{B}\,x_T.
$$

By defining the following submatrices

$$
e^{\hat{A}\,T} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
X_{11} & X_{12} \\ X_{21} & X_{22}
\end{bmatrix}, \quad
\int_0^T e^{\hat{A}(T - \tau)}d\tau\,\hat{B} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
Y_1 \\ Y_2
\end{bmatrix}
$$

then it is possible obtain the following expression

$$
x(T) = X_{11}\,x(0) + X_{12}\,\lambda(0) + Y_1\,x_T
$$

since $x(T)=x_T$ and $x(0)=x_0$, then this can be used to solve for $\lambda(0)$

$$
\lambda(0) = X_{12}^{-1} ((I - Y_1)\,x_T - X_{11}\,x_0) = 
\begin{bmatrix}
-X_{12}^{-1}\,X_{11} & X_{12}^{-1} (I - Y_1)
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_0 \\ x_T
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Combining this with the expression for the state as a function of time yields

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x(t) \\ \lambda(t)
\end{bmatrix} = e^{\hat{A}\,t} 
\begin{bmatrix}
I & 0 \\
-X_{12}^{-1}\,X_{11} & X_{12}^{-1} (I - Y_1)
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_0 \\ x_T
\end{bmatrix} + \int_0^t e^{\hat{A}(t - \tau)}d\tau\,\hat{B}\,x_T
$$

so from this it can be concluded that the solution of the state $x$ as a function of time should be linear in $x_0$ and $x_T$

$$
x(t) = \Phi(t)
\begin{bmatrix}
x_0 \\ x_T
\end{bmatrix}
$$

where $\Phi(t)$ is a function of time, independently of $x$. But the solution for $\Phi(t)$ might change if a difference $A$, $B$, $\rho$ or $T$ would be used. If $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ then $\Phi(t)\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times2\,n}$.

I have only quickly skimmed through the paper you linked to, but I am not sure why that author states there are only 56 "transitions" (which should correspond to the columns of $\Phi(t)$), while the state space dimension is of size 129. Since in the general case I would actually expect twice as many transitions as states, so 258. But maybe the author put constraints on the allowed $x_0$ and $x_T$ which reduces the span of $\Phi(t)$.

Comment: Thank you Kwin! I think the authors deliberately chose 56 transitions based on other research. Wouldn't there be $ 2^{258} $ possible transitions? That is, there are $ 2^{129} $ possible arrangements of the initial state vector and $2^{129} $ possible arrangements of the final state vector, if both are binary.